# Error Importing Theano on Windows 10: Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

When I try to import Theano in Python 2.7, I get the following error message:

```
'C:Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -LC:\\Anaconda\\libs -use_fast_math -LC:\\Anaconda\\libs --compiler-bindir C:Program Files (x86)Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0VCbinamd64 -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=18715462c72ed6afcd7ca5d52813ce90,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\Anaconda\\include -IC:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof -o C:\\Users\\JACOB #1\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.10240-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\Anaconda\\libs -LC:\\Anaconda -lpython27 -lcublas -lcudart
```

I noticed that in the  --compiler-bindir  section, the path has no slashes (C:Program Files (x86)Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0VCbinamd64). I have checked my PATH, THEANO_FLAGS, and .theanorc.txt file and none have this path without the slashes. Is there a way to resolve this?

When I try to paste this command, inserting the slashes, into the command prompt, I get the following results:

```
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

This makes no sense to me, as the first entry in my PATH is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

My .theanorc.txt is as follows:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[cuda]
root = -LJ:\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0

[nvcc]
flags = -LC:\Anaconda\libs
fastmath = True
compiler-bindir = -LC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by setting windows environment variable, instead of directly mentioning the path in compiler-bindir.

You can set windows environment variable by right click on

"start->computer->properties->advanced system settings"

Comment: tesseract has specified that the first entry in the PATH is indeed the amd64 bin...

Comment: tesseract has verified PATH, while I am suggesting to create a environment variable so that  --compiler-bindir = $VSPATH

Comment: Oh, my bad!  Yes, I understood what you meant!   :P

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `cl.exe` actually exists in the directory:

**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64`**

***If it doesn't***, then install it(along with all the other MS runtime files for C++, which doesn't come by default) by running the VS setup, select Modify option, then expand and select:

**`Programming Language -> C++`**

and install.

Hopefully, now it might work. Please be patient as that download might take quite a while...

> **PS: Iff possible, migrate your Theano workbase to UNIX based OS like (Ubuntu/Kali Linux/Manjaro) + Anaconda for SciPy and NumPy, as it poses much less of a problem than in Windows**